# IIS, SSL, and securing a folder (Require SSL)

Tags: ssl, iis, certificate

I have a PHP website under Windows 7/IIS 7 that I will require to use smart card authentication.
I have configured the bindings for the default website for HTTPS port 443 and created and selected a self-signed certificate for use with it. I currently have things setup to only require the certificate when navigating to a specific folder by way of a button click (login).

What is currently happening on my local machine is that the certificate prompt does not show when attempting to navigate to the folder and I get a "This page can’t be displayed" message in IE.

Help?

Comment: no relevant .conf/.htaccess examples, no help... this is not a jobs board where you "hire" someone to help you. YOU post the relevant code, and then wait for someone to (maybe) try and help.

Comment: There is no code to share. It's pretty much a web server/config question....

Comment: it may not be executable "code", but the conf stuff is STILL a form of code, and without we cannot do ANYTHING to help you. We are not psychic, and our fancy fake magic crystal balls are all in the shop, so we can't even pretend to read your mind.